# Swift Facebook Invite Friends

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to create Facebook Invite button in my app. Whenever a user clicks "Invite friends" new windows opens and then closes after 2-3 secs with this error in console:

```
"Error: Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 \"(null)\")"
```

This is how I'm creating invite window:

```
func inviteFacebookFriends(){
    let dialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
    let content:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "http://example.com/")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = URL(string: "http://example.com/image.jpg")
    dialog.content = content
    dialog.delegate = self
    do {
        try dialog.validate()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    dialog.show()
}
```

All delegates are in the class

```
func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    debugPrint("Success: " + String(describing: results))
}
func appInviteDialog(_ appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    debugPrint("Error: " + String(describing: error))
}
```

In my .plist I have `FacebookAppID` and `FacebookDisplayName`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you solved your problem.i face same problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

in your AppDelegate.

[Facebook App delegate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#xcode)

Comment: I have that in my AppDelegate

Comment: activate app as well ?

Comment: If your app crash on invite or attempting to invite. Then you need to add this line [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];